# ggplot using geom_bar - distinguishing a single bar with color

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to produce a bar chart with ggplot2 in which a single bar is distiguished with a designated colour.

To illustrate with a simple data frame:

```
type <- c('apples','pears','bananas','plums','melons','pineapples')
weight <- c(14,11,19,16,12,8)
fruit <- data.frame(type,weight)
```

This is what I have so far to produce the plot:

```
library("ggplot2")
f <- ggplot(fruit, aes(x=type, y=weight))

f + geom_bar(stat=’identity", fill = (ifelse(fruit$type=='bananas', 'yellow', 'gray')))
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? (Except for your `’` instead of `"`.)

Comment: I'm getting 'melons' filled in yellow when it should be 'bananas'.

Comment: Ah ok. Try `f + geom_col(aes(fill = ifelse(fruit$type=='bananas', 'yellow', 'gray'))) + scale_fill_identity()`

Answer (score 1):

The order of bars in ggplot depends on the order of the levels of your factor variable `fruit$type`.

Replacing your last line with the following will work, because we require that the factor level is banana:

```
f + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = (ifelse(levels(fruit$type)=='bananas', 'yellow', 'gray')))
```

Comment: Both Axeman's and Robert's solutions work fine. Many thanks to both.